# Why ZMQApplication doesn't send variables from query to handler class?

Tags: python, tornado, pyzmq

I have some trouble with ZMQApplication

I have a code in python for example

```
...
application = ZMQApplication([
    (r'/account/([^/]*)/([^.]*)', AccountHandler),
])
...
```

and class AccountHandler

```
class AccountHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,data1,data2):
        ...
```

when I send query /account/test/123 python throw exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 954, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

and in data1 I can see the full query url = '/account/test/123'

If I try to load  /account/test/123/234 then receive as expected 404

Comment: I fix this. I have a server on tornado and worker at zmq. And in server I proxy all requests to the worker like `(r'/(.*)',ZMQRequestHandlerProxy,{"proxy":proxy,"timeout":CONFIG.ZMQ.WEB_PROXY_TIMEOUT})` . But we need to write all routes the same in worker ie: `(r"/account/([a-z0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/*(.*)", ZMQRequestHandlerProxy, {"proxy": proxy, "timeout": CONFIG.ZMQ.WEB_PROXY_TIMEOUT})`